# how to remove text from div where it hase multiple siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```html
<div class="latest_posts style3 latest_posts--style2 latest_posts2 clearfix eluidf4c60403  latestposts2--dark element-scheme--dark">
<h3 class="m_title m_title_ext text-custom latest_posts2-elm-title" itemprop="headline"></h3>
 VIEW ALL               
<ul class="posts latest_posts2-posts">
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/law-for-bank/" itemprop="headline">Law For Bank</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/tech-blog/" itemprop="headline">Tech Blog</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/blog-about-tech-and-telcos/" itemprop="headline">Blog About Tech and Telcos</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

```html
<div class="latest_posts style3 latest_posts--style2 latest_posts2 clearfix eluidf4c60403  latestposts2--dark element-scheme--dark">
<h3 class="m_title m_title_ext text-custom latest_posts2-elm-title" itemprop="headline"></h3>
 VIEW ALL               
<ul class="posts latest_posts2-posts">
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/law-for-bank/" itemprop="headline">Law For Bank</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/tech-blog/" itemprop="headline">Tech Blog</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/blog-about-tech-and-telcos/" itemprop="headline">Blog About Tech and Telcos</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

`

VIEW ALL               

   
      Law For Bank
      December 4, 2020
      
   
   
      Tech Blog
      December 4, 2020
      
   
   
      Blog About Tech and Telcos
      December 4, 2020
      
   
 
`How can we remove the "VIEW ALL" text from this given ``
how can it be done.

Comment: See here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/remove-any-text-not-inside-element-tag-on-a-web-page-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

To access text node you have to check if the `nodeName` value of a Element is equal to `"#text"` I this case I get all content of the `DIV` with class `latest_posts` and access all it children using the  `childNodes` property after getting that element with a `querySelector`.

After I have retrive the list of `children` I can loop through that list and return only child which are not of type `#text`

```js
let latest_posts = document.querySelector('.latest_posts');
let newContent = latest_posts.cloneNode();

newContent.innerHTML = "";

Array.from(latest_posts.childNodes).forEach(child => {
  if(child.nodeName != "#text") {
    newContent.append(child);
  }
});

latest_posts.innerHTML = newContent.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="latest_posts style3 latest_posts--style2 latest_posts2 clearfix eluidf4c60403  latestposts2--dark element-scheme--dark">
<h3 class="m_title m_title_ext text-custom latest_posts2-elm-title" itemprop="headline"></h3>
 VIEW ALL               
<ul class="posts latest_posts2-posts">
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/law-for-bank/" itemprop="headline">Law For Bank</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/tech-blog/" itemprop="headline">Tech Blog</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="post latest_posts2-post">
      <h4 class="title latest_posts2-title"><a class="latest_posts2-title-link" href="http://wpstaging.a2zcreatorz.com/deloitte/design/blog-about-tech-and-telcos/" itemprop="headline">Blog About Tech and Telcos</a></h4>
      <div class="latest_posts2-date"><span>December 4, 2020</span></div>
      <div class="latest_posts2-itemSep  clearfix"></div>
   </li>
 </ul>
<div>
```